# How to add rows by splitting columns in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

Problem with this code is that when we want to add a row, it will add a row in only one column. Please can anybody tell me how to split the columns?

JavaScript:

```
    function Myfunction(tableid) {
        var table=document.getElementById("tablerow");            
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;            
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);            
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);

        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <body>
       <table id="tablerow" border="1" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td><center>1</center></td>
            <td><input type="textbox" name="" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="textbox" name="" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="textbox" name="" value=""></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><center>2</center></td>
            <td><input type="textbox" name="" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="textbox" name="" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="textbox" name="" value=""></td>
         </tr>

         <center><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="Myfunction()">
```

Comment: you didn't close neither the `table`-tag nor the `body`. Wont solve the Problem, but anyway..

Answer (score 0):

You have four columns in the table but you were trying to insert row with only three cells. This resulted in invalid table structure.

Also, you should put each cell in its proper position by giving correct index when calling `insertCell()` method.

Here is working code that inserts row with four cells, first has "running index" and the rest have text boxes, each and its own textbox:

```
function Myfunction(tableid) {
    var table=document.getElementById("tablerow");        
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;        
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);        

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    cell4.appendChild(element4);
}
```

[​Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/mebph/).

This works, but pretty "clumsy". To have it more flexible and better written, add another function:

```
function CellWithTextbox(row, index) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(index);
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.type = "text";
    cell.appendChild(element);
    return cell;
}
```

Then the last part of your function will turn to those simple lines:

```
var cell2 = CellWithTextbox(row, 1);
var cell3 = CellWithTextbox(row, 2);
var cell4 = CellWithTextbox(row, 3);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mebph/1/).